# Check if one branch is entirely "on top of" another

Tags: git

I'm looking for a command like:

```
git some-command branch1 branch2
```

that will return true if and only if branch2 is entirely on top of branch1.  There should be a single, straight line of commits leading from branch1 to branch2.

This should therefore return true if branch2 has been rebased on branch1, but not, for example, if branch1 has been merged into branch2.

Is there a clean builtin way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is a way to tell the difference. Consider these repositories.

> branch2 has been rebased on branch1

```
A - B - C - F - G [branch1]
                 \
                  D - E - F [branch2]
```

> branch1 has been merged into branch2

```
A - B - C - F - G  [branch1]
         \       \
          D - E - M - H [branch2]
```

> There should be a single, straight line of commits leading from branch1 to branch2.

The problem is in both instances there is a straight line of commits from branch2 to branch1. The first is F -> E -> D -> G. The second is H -> M -> G.

Maybe it can be redefined as there are no *merge* commits between branch2 and branch1? That would be `git log --oneline branch1...branch2 --merges`, but this is easily spoiled by merges within branch2. For example...

```
A - B - C - F - G  [branch1]
                 \
                  H - I ----- N [branch2]
                       \     /
                        J - K
```

Does that count? Up to you.

How about this?

```
A - B - C - F - G - X - Y [branch1]
                 \
                  H - I [branch2]
```

Did it start like the below, and then more commits were added?

```
A - B - C - F - G [branch1]
                 \
                  H - I [branch2]
```

Or did it start like this, branch1 was branched off branch3, and branch3 was deleted?

```
A - B - C - F - G [branch3]
                 \
                  H - I [branch2]
```

---

If you want to check if a branch needs to be rebased, the simple answer is to do the rebase.

Comment: "The second is H -> M -> G."  This would be illegal because M has two parents. So "no forks in the road" are allowed.  The context, as you may have guessed, is to enforce clean history in a GH repository.  We create feature branches off master, then merge them back into master.  If other PRs have been merged since your original branch forked off, you need to pull master and rebase your work on it before it can be merged.  We want to enforce this using GH actions.

Comment: Hence "If you want to check if a branch needs to be rebased, the simple answer is to do the rebase" is not an option, because they will often require conflict resolution that can't be automated.  However, we would like to block merging of PRs that have not been rebased on master.  Re: "Does that count? Up to you," that topology would occur rarely in our workflow, and it would be acceptable to disallow it even it was technically a false positive.

Comment: @Jonah In that case, a simple check for merge commits in the feature branch should suffice: `git log --oneline branch1...branch2 --merges` I can't think, off the top of my head, why a feature branch would need a merge commit. And I do agree that feature branches should be updated via rebase. OTOH be careful with the up-to-date check. The submitter is not in control of when their PR is merged. I'd suggest a policy that a PR must be up to date when submitted, but ultimately make it the integrator's problem to ensure it's up to date when merged.